# Smart way to do a numeric integral of a recursive function defined by symbolic integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, evaluation, numerical-value

I have a little question. I need a smart way to compute a numerical integral.
The standard way to compute a numerical integral, in multiple variables, is, for example, the following:

```
NIntegrate[x y , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

The time of computation is very small.
Now let me define the following recursive functions:

```
l[0]:=x[0]
l[h_]:=Integrate[l[h-1],{x[h-1],0,x[h]}]
```

so, for example, we have:

```
l[1]=x[1]^2/2
l[2]=x[2]^3/6
```

and so on.
Now if I compute the following numeric integral

```
NIntegrate[l[2], {x[2], 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

I obtain the output of '0.0416667', and it is correct.
This is easy because, thanks to the symbolic integration in the recursive formula, we have a closed form for every function 'l[h]', with 'h' positive integer.
Now I modify the recursive formula in this way

```
l[0]:=Cos[x[0]-Sin[Cos[Tan[Sin[Cos[1-Sin[Cos[x[0]]]]]]]]]
l[h_]:=Integrate[l[h-1],{x[h-1],0,x[h]}]
```

Obviously 'l[0]' is very difficult function, that probably, doesn't admit a closed form.
If now I try to do the following numeric integration

```
NIntegrate[l[1], {x[1], 0, 0.1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5] (*1*)
```

the output appears after a very very long time of evaluation.
Instead if I write manually the form of the previous numeric integral, with boundaries of integration, like the following:

```
NIntegrate[l[0],{x[1],0,0.1},{x[0],0,x[1]},AccuracyGoal->5] (*2*)
```

I obtain the output instantly.

The long time of evaluation of the numeric integral (1) is caused by the fact that the numeric integral of 'l[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5QLn.png)' needs to evaluate previously of numeric evaluation, the following symbolic integral:

```
Integrate[l[0], {x[0], 0, x[1]}]
```

this comes from the recursive formula for 'l[h]', where 'l[0]' is a very ugly function.

Now I can do my question: there is a way to define the recursive formula, in a way that if I put a recursive function in the final numeric integral, there is NO need to do the symbolic integral of a very ugly function?

Thanks for any tips and helps.
I hope we will find a solution for this problem.
Thanks again!

I add the following part in a second moment.
Probabily the following can help us to achive the goal.
I define the recursive function like:

```
l[0] := f[x0_]
l[h_] := Integrate[l[h - 1], {x[h - 1], 0, x[h]}]
```

So if I write 'l[2]', for example, I obtain the following output (I paste an immage for a clear visualization):

[image]

So this is pretty, but If now I try to compute numerically the integral evaluating the expression of 'l[2]' for 'f[x[0]]' equal to the ugly function of my example

```
NIntegrate[l[2]/.f[x0_]->Cos[x[0] - Sin[Cos[Tan[Sin[Cos[1 - Sin[Cos[x[0]]]]]]]]], {x[2], 0, 0.1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

I obtained the correct result but after the same very very long time of computation.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** an answer but rather an extended comment.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Functions that are defined recursively should make use of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid unnecessary repetition of calculations (see [`Functions That Remember Values They Have Found`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#202640595) and  [`workflow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html)).

```
l[0] := x[0]
l[h_] := l[h] = Integrate[l[h - 1], {x[h - 1], 0, x[h]}]
```

Note the use of memoization in the definition of `l[h]`

```
seq = l /@ Range[0, 5]

(* {x[0], x[1]^2/2, x[2]^3/6, x[3]^4/24, x[4]^5/120, x[5]^6/720} *)
```

In this specific case, by inspection, the closed form for the terms of this sequence are

```
l2[n_] = x[n]^(n + 1)/(n + 1)!;
```

Verifying the equivalence of `l` and `l2` for an extended range,

```
And @@ Table[l[n] == l2[n], {n, 0, 20}]

(* True *)
```

The associated integrals are then

```
int[n_] = Assuming[n >= 0, Integrate[l2[n], {x[n], 0, 1}]]

(* 1/Gamma[3 + n] *)
```

Comparing with your original example,

```
{int[2], int[2] // N}

(* {1/24, 0.0416667} *)
```

Memoization should also be used in your second example; however, finding a closed form expression is unlikely.

Comment: @MarcoB - thanks. I corrected.